# How to get Pinterest Logged In User Details using Access Token

Tags: node.js, axios, pinterest

I have completed the Oauth2 Access Token Retrieval flow for a user and now I wish to use that access token to read the user profile information. How do I pass the access token to the
provided endpoint as documented here?

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/v5/#operation/user_account/get

Their documentations are not so clear on this.

Here is what I have tried:

```
            const { access_token } = responseData;
            let userAccountDataUrl = `https://api.pinterest.com/v5/user_account`;
            axios.get(userAccountDataUrl, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `pinterest_oauth2 (user_accounts:read)`
                }
            }).then((userAccountResponse) => {
                const userData = userAccountResponse.data;
                console.log(`FetchedUserAccount=${JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2)}`);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(`Error fetching user account due to ${JSON.stringify(e.response.data)}`);
            });
```

If you've worked with pinterest api I would really appreciate your input.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your header should be something like this :

```
headers: {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${your token}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  followRedirect: false,}
```

Comment: it gives me CORS error even tho it works with Chrome plugin